# GET() webservice call in ServiceNow throws a Number Format Exception

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, servicenow

Get webservice call which fetches a single incident from ServiceNow throws an exception that says, "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: For input string: Normal", "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: Normal". But the input that I'm giving is a sys_id which is a **string** and the object of Get webservice also expects a string .

```
Get getInc = new Get();
GetResponse resp = new GetResponse();
getInc.setSys_id(sysid); //sysid is of type String
resp = stub.get(getInc);
```

I do not understand where does a NumberFormatException come from in this context . Could someone please help?
Stack trace is given below.

```
    org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: For input string: "Normal"
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Normal"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at      org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToInteger(ConverterUtil.java:839)
 at     com.service_now.www.ServiceNow_incidentStub$GetResponse$Factory.parse(ServiceNow_incidentSt    ub.java:10561)    (http://www.ServiceNow_incidentStub$GetResponse$Factory.parse%28ServiceNow_incidentStub.jav   a:10561%29)
 at com.service_now.www.ServiceNow_incidentStub.fromOM(ServiceNow_incidentStub.java:14029) (http://www.ServiceNow_incidentStub.fromOM%28ServiceNow_incidentStub.java:14029%29)
```

Note: **elementFormDefault** value is set to False, i.e the option is not ticked.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: Any chance you have a full stack trace for the AxisFault? Also, it may be worthwhile to issue the same SOAP get using SoapUI or curl, and then post the outbound SOAP envelope and response, as there may be something there to indicate what's happening.

Comment: yea, sure. I will edit the question and put the stack trace overthere. Btw, I can retrieve the record successfully using SOAPUI and even in another instance of service now with the same code. So I assume it's the problem with the serviceNow instance I am using.Hence, If you could direct me on where to check for the problem in the current instance that I have, it would be helpful. :)

Comment: When you get a response in SoapUI, does the response payload contain the string "Normal" anywhere? If so, lookup the field that is returning that value in the WSDL, and see what the 'type' is. My guess is that there's a field that's being reported as a numeric type in the WSDL, but is not returning a number in reality. If that's the case, you'll need to check the sys_dictionary record for that field on the target instance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the sample Java project for getting records from ServiceNow's SOAP API at http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Java_Apache_Axis2_Web_Services_Client_Examples#gsc.tab=0 as a reference and then comparing this with your implementation. Also if you need a demo servicenow instance to test against you can sign up for a dev instance at https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/program/developer.

Hope that helps,
Bryan